# Problema com box-sizing

Tags: css

Tenho um `input` e gostaria de colocar um `box-sizing` pois vou usar `padding-left` e não gostaria de mexer na largura do elemento.

Meu HTML:

```
<div class="contato">
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Meu CSS:

```
.contato input {
    width: 480px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
}
```

O `box-sizing` não está funcionando, conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é o `box-sizing: border-box;` que quer usar? o `padding-box` ainda não é suportado por quase nenhum browser...

Comment: Não sabia. É o `padding-box` mesmo, pois gostaria que os 15px do padding não fossem somados ao width do elemento.

Comment: Nesse caso é o mesmo que o `border-box`. Dê [uma olhada aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) acho que o comportamento/descrição com o padding é igual.

Comment: Se juntar uma imagem com o problema seria bom, no caso de eu não estar a perceber bem o problema...

Comment: Ahh, você já esclareceu minha dúvida, eu não sabia que o `border-box` serviria para a minha necessidade. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `padding-box` [ainda não é suportado por quase nenhum browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Acho que pode usar `box-sizing: border-box;`, para o que explica acho que é essa a solução. A descrição da MDN diz:

> **border-box**
>   A largura e altura includem o `padding` e o `border` mas não a `margin`
>   *The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.*